# MySql: sum value based on state field on millions rows table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of rows (SF_COLLECTIONS)

```
ID MEMBERID COLLECTIONID CARDID STATE (D / M) HOWMANY
1  1        1            1      D             1
2  1        1            2      D             2
3  2        1            1      M             1
4  2        1            2      M             1
5  2        2            3      D             1
6  1        2            3      M             2
```

and I want to know for every COLLECTIONID the SUM of HOWMANY field for STATE=D and STATE=M
So I try this approach

```
select COLLECTIONID,
sum(if(STATE='D',HOWMANY,0)) as HMD,
sum(if(STATE='M',HOWMANY,0)) as HMM
from SF_COLLECTIONS
group by COLLECTIONID
```

and it takes about 15 seconds to answer

Any suggestions to get better performances?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many millions?

Comment: There is no way to index your query with expectation of a big improvement.

Comment: @P.Salmon near 10 millions

Comment: can you try add an index on (collectionid, state), and try `select sum(howmany) ... group by collectionid, state`, and then pivot/sum the result so that it meets your require? cuz I think with the index, it will be faster for mysql to sum the howmany field and I think it will reduce a lot of if statement of your solution

Comment: What kind of data is this?  If it is "sensor" or "log" data that is coming in continually, but not changing once it is written, then a Summary table is the best solution.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; a change to the `PRIMARY KEY` may be in store.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT COLLECTIONID,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATE='D' THEN HOWMANY END) AS HMD,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATE='M' THEN HOWMANY END) AS HMM
FROM SF_COLLECTIONS
GROUP BY COLLECTIONID;

Duration / Fetch Time
0.00068 sec / 0.000012 sec
```

Your existing_query:

```
SELECT COLLECTIONID,
SUM(IF(STATE='D',HOWMANY,0)) AS HMD,
SUM(IF(STATE='M',HOWMANY,0)) AS HMM
FROM SF_COLLECTIONS
GROUP BY COLLECTIONID;

Duration / Fetch Time
0.00072 sec / 0.000012 sec
```

Only 6 rows there is 0.00004 difference :
For 10 million rows, I think It is noticeable:)

Comment: case query: 14.0240
if query: 14.4039

Comment: OK,Clear. I tried to solve it by Range Columns partitioning; however end result was almost the same values.